# Using ajax inside the Web Content Display Portlet

Tags: ajax, spring, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using the liferay community edition 6.0. One of the pages will be using only the Web Content Display portlet to add content to it. I want to achieve the following inside that content i will load some html links that will be used to download some pdf. I want to add an ajax call to me domain before the actual redirect to the link has been done.

My question is the following. I've used the hook feature of liferay to add a java script ajax function in to the view.jsp. The click event is caught in the view.jsp but since there is no controller i don't know how to propagate this event to the domain.

So far i've done this function on my custom create portlet that are done using Spring MVC. But for this specific portlet i cant seem to find the controller or what ever handler the Web Content Display is using(if any).

Can someone please tell me if this is possible and point me in some direction if it is possible.

Comment: Clarification: You want to fire an ajax query to the server from the Web-content Display portlet and return something?

Comment: If you can elaborate on your requirement a little more than it would be great

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what functionality you're trying to implement here, but I'll try to help. You can make an Ajax call to another jsp in your hook from your view.jsp.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/jsp/path/your.jsp",
   data: "country="+country,
   success: function() {
   ...
  }
  ...
});
```